# OpenCV 2.3.1: how to tell if haartraining is stuck or still working (on TINY example)

Tags: opencv

I am using `opencv_haartraining` for the first time, using OpenCV 2.3.1 on Mac OS X Lion.

I am trying to train a very quick example. I am only using 23 positive examples and 45 negative examples. Yet `opencv_haartraining` has been using 100% of one core of my 2010 Macbook Air for at least 30 hours!

Here are the relevant files:

- The directory http://stanford.edu/~jonr1/haartraining_test_1/
- The vec file of positive samples http://stanford.edu/~jonr1/haartraining_test_1/vec_positive_samples/vec_positive_samples.vec

  - The bg (negative) examples http://stanford.edu/~jonr1/haartraining_test_1/bg_negative_examples.txt
  - The intermediate results produced so far  http://stanford.edu/~jonr1/haartraining_test_1/results/

The vec file was produced by following this tutorial http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html , using that author's program `mergevec` to combine vec files individually produced by `createsamples`.

The output of opencv_haartraining was:

```
Data dir name: /Users/jon/Tabletop/haartraining_test_1/results
Vec file name: /Users/jon/Tabletop/haartraining_test_1/vec_positive_samples/vec_positive_samples.vec
BG  file name: /var/folders/85/96xv8qxx5ssc7ndg50s5lp480000gn/T/tmpZ2bASi.txt, is a vecfile: no
Num pos: 115
Num neg: 45
Num stages: 20
Num splits: 2 (tree as weak classifier)
Mem: 200 MB
Symmetric: TRUE
Min hit rate: 0.995000
Max false alarm rate: 0.500000
Weight trimming: 0.950000
Equal weights: FALSE
Mode: BASIC
Width: 20
Height: 20
Applied boosting algorithm: GAB
Error (valid only for Discrete and Real AdaBoost): misclass
Max number of splits in tree cascade: 0
Min number of positive samples per cluster: 500
Required leaf false alarm rate: 9.53674e-07

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+
|  0|
+---+


Number of features used : 41910

Parent node: NULL

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 1
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-| 0.910420| 1.000000| 0.044444| 0.012500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 2.00
Number of used features: 2

Parent node: NULL
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+
|  0|
+---+

   0


Parent node: 0

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.283019
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.965048| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.018750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.903213| 1.000000| 0.288889| 0.025000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 3.00
Number of used features: 4

Parent node: 0
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+
|  0|  1|
+---+---+

   0---1


Parent node: 1

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.338346
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.961620| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.043750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.660077| 1.000000| 0.622222| 0.043750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   3| 88%|-| 0.142538| 1.000000| 0.044444| 0.012500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 4.00
Number of used features: 6

Parent node: 1
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|
+---+---+---+

   0---1---2


Parent node: 2

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.145631
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.975839| 1.000000| 0.777778| 0.025000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.904803| 1.000000| 0.244444| 0.037500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 3.00
Number of used features: 4

Parent node: 2
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|
+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3


Parent node: 3

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.0293926
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.981092| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.031250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2| 91%|+|-0.820519| 1.000000| 0.333333| 0.031250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 3.00
Number of used features: 4

Parent node: 3
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|
+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4


Parent node: 4

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.0244965
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.964250| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.025000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-1.801320| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.025000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   3| 88%|-|-0.938272| 1.000000| 0.177778| 0.006250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 4.00
Number of used features: 6

Parent node: 4
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4---5


Parent node: 5

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.0100245
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.975839| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.037500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.109149| 1.000000| 0.133333| 0.037500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 3.00
Number of used features: 4

Parent node: 5
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4---5---6


Parent node: 6

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.00587774
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.870814| 1.000000| 0.800000| 0.050000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-0.437010| 1.000000| 0.200000| 0.050000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 3.00
Number of used features: 4

Parent node: 6
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7


Parent node: 7

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.00269655
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.825750| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.087500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2| 89%|+|-1.098274| 1.000000| 0.911111| 0.093750|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   3| 99%|-|-0.387003| 1.000000| 0.222222| 0.050000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 5.00
Number of used features: 6

Parent node: 7
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8


Parent node: 8

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.000656714
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.780975| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.125000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+|-1.143491| 1.000000| 0.866667| 0.125000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   3|100%|-|-1.267461| 1.000000| 0.355556| 0.037500|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 5.00
Number of used features: 6

Parent node: 8
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9


Parent node: 9

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
NEG: 45 0.000245695
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 1.00
Precalculation time: 0.00
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   1|100%|-|-0.982759| 1.000000| 1.000000| 0.006250|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   2|100%|+| 0.017238| 1.000000| 0.000000| 0.000000|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
Stage training time: 2.00
Number of used features: 4

Parent node: 9
Chosen number of splits: 0

Total number of splits: 0

Tree Classifier
Stage
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  1|  2|  3|  4|  5|  6|  7|  8|  9| 10|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

   0---1---2---3---4---5---6---7---8---9--10


Parent node: 10

*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 115 115 1.000000
```

All of this output was produced in the first 5 minutes of the run. After producing this output, it has proceeded to run with 100% of one core for 30 hours (so far) with no further output.

My question is: how can I tell if haartraining has crashed in this particular case, and more generally, **does anyone know how to modify `cvhaartraining.cpp` so that it periodically outputs its status?** Thanks a million!

(Related questions, both without answers:

- [OpenCV 2.2 Haartraining Hanging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400527/opencv-2-2-haartraining-hanging)
- [OpenCV: How to know the progress status of HaarTraining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483690/opencv-how-to-know-the-progress-status-of-haartraining)

)

Comment: Looks like it hangs to me. I used opencv_haartraining on ~1000 positive, ~1000 negative and it takes about a day only. But don't just kill it yet, I will do some test on my Linux box and get back to you on this.

Comment: Already killed it, sorry (was worried about the temperature I was subjecting my Macbook battery too, and wear on the fan). But I'll rerun it on the same or similar data so we can have a process to attach to.

Comment: Have you had more luck with your second run?

Comment: Haven't had time yet for a second run, but when I do I'll start a second bounty.

Comment: I'd let it run for a few hours and then attach a debugger to the running process to determine where the execution is. Maybe you will be able to directly tell where is the problem by stepping through the code a few times and check that the code actually changes something (esp. variables used in conditions). Otherwise add some `printf`'s to the code around the breakpoint and hope it will reveal something.

Comment: There's also similar thread on OpenCV Yahoo tech group with a code for giving some additional feedback to determine whether the code entered an endless loop: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/45080

Comment: @stativ Your link is the correct answer. If you post your comment as an answer (and quote the relevant action items), I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's also similar thread on the OpenCV Yahoo tech group with a code by michael_p_horton for giving some additional feedback to determine whether the code entered an endless loop: [tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/45080](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/45080)

To sum up the mentioned thread, there are two places where haartraining can go wild.

The first one is easy to catch by checking the output – you need the HR (Hit Rate) to increase and FA (False Alarm) to decrease. If this doesn't happen, the training entered an infinite loop.

However the issue you are experiencing, according to the maxenglander's answer, is an infinite loop in the `icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromBG`. To check for this you need to dig into the `cvhaartraining.cpp` code and add some debug output.

To quote the answer from Yahoo groups, you need to modify the `icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromBG` implementation in a following way (look for the cascade-eval() line and then add the CV_VERBOSE code):

```
icvGetAuxImages( &img, &sum, &tilted, &sqsum, normfactor );
if( cascade->eval( cascade, sumdata, tilteddata, *normfactor ) != 0.0F )
    break;

/* Display progress on negative image selection */
#ifdef CV_VERBOSE
if( thread_consumed_count % 1000 == 0 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "%3d%%, %d negatives of %d required, %d images
    tested\r", (int) ( 100.0 * (i - first) / count ), (i-first), count,
    thread_consumed_count );
    fflush( stderr );
}
#endif /* CV_VERBOSE */
```

> If this starts displaying messages like "0%, 0 negatives of 972
>   required, 10000000 images tested" you've entered an endless loop.

One final note – with the OpenCV 2.4 the relevant code is in the `icvGetHaarTrainingData` function.

Answer (score 4):

From looking at `haartraining/cvhaartraining.cpp`, it looks like your process was at this line before you cancelled:

```
negcount = icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromBG( training_data, poscount, nneg,
    (CvIntHaarClassifier*) tcc, &false_alarm, bg_vecfile ? bgfilename : NULL );
```

You could drill down into functions that are called by `icvGetHaarTrainingDataFromBG`, add `printf` statements, and re-compile. I have been having my training runs hang as well (I'm using `opencv_traincascade`), and would like to see just where things are getting stuck. I may try sprinkling in `printf` statements into `traincascade/traincascade.cpp` to see why my runs are hanging.

Max

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  My runs are also also hanging.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the description of haartraining, you find the default value of

```
-minpos <min_number_of_positive_samples_per_cluster = 500>
```

Since you only have 115 positive samples, this might be your problem... Perhaps you didn't specify this parameter, and this is causing the training to never end. Try setting it to 75

```
haartraining <your params> -minpos 75
```

Just my idea, not verified. Please let me know your findings

Answer (score 1):

Problem is with your positive.txt and positive.vec file.(not negative)

Make it sure that positive.txt/positive.dat file contains 115 positive samples

i.e. Num pos: 115

Note:

**npos != number of positive images**

**npos = Number of samples in all positive images**

If you have multiple objects in single image then its positive.txt descriptive file must contain multiple entries.

It will be helpful if you post here positive.txt and createsamples.exe output.

Answer (score 1):

For now from my experience I concluded:

If it freeze in table header or in a table like this

```
*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 11342 11342 1.000000
NEG: 1102 1
BACKGROUND PROCESSING TIME: 0.03
Precalculation time: 1.92
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  N |%SMP|F|  ST.THR |    HR   |    FA   | EXP. ERR|
+----+----+-+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

it still running
but if it freeze in "cluster" text like this

```
*** 1 cluster ***
POS: 11342 11342 1.000000
```

it may hanging

The source it hangs could be your positive images is to different or your negative images has similar features so it's difficult to classify them

pre-process your positive images first before training